# Proof of the spectral formula for the expected number of steps in a random walk

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, graph-theory, random-walk, spectral-graph-theory

In a paper by Lovász (see reference at the end), there is the derivation of a spectral formula for the hitting time, which is the expected number of steps to get to a node t, starting at s, in a random walk on the graph.

It starts with the equation:

(1) $H(i,j) = 1 + \frac{1}{d(i)} \sum_{v \in \Gamma(i)} H(v,j) \ \ i \ne j$

I tried transforming this equation to a matrix equation and got
to:

$H = J + MH$

(I'm not sure that what is above is correct)

After (1), the author just straight says that the matrix F is

(2) F = J + MH - H

And that F is diagonalizable.

That's where I got stuck. Where did this matrix F come from? How can he know that it's diagonalizable?

Note that:

$J$ is the matrix of all ones. ($J_{ij} = 1$ for any i,j)

$M$ is the matrix of transition probabilities. $M_{ij} = \frac{1}{degree(i)}$

$H_{ij}$ = the expected number of steps in a random walk from i to j.

Could someone help me with the steps of this proof? I couldn't also make much sense of what comes later.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Source of Lovász paper: https://cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr1029.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (1) says that for $i \ne j$, $$H_{ij} = J_{ij} + \sum_v M_{iv} H_{vj}.$$ (I am writing $J_{ij}$ for the mysterious quantity otherwise known as the number $1$, and writing $M_{iv}$ in the sum both stands in for $\frac1{\deg(i)}$ and lets us extend the sum over all $v$.) In other words, for $i \ne j$, $H_{ij} = J_{ij} + (MH)_{ij}$.

However, we cannot write $H = J + MH$ from here, because of that pesky qualifier "for $i \ne j$". In other words, the matrices $H$ and $J+MH$ agree in their off-diagonal entries, but not in their diagonal entries.

This is exactly the same as saying that if we define a matrix $F$ to be $(J + MH) - H$, then $F$ is... not just *diagonalizable*, but *diagonal*. For $i \ne j$, we have $F_{ij} = J_{ij} + (MH)_{ij} - H_{ij}$, which is $0$ by equation (1). Therefore only the diagonal of $F$ can have nonzero entries.

In the next step, Lovász brings in the stationary distribution $\pi$, which is defined by the property $\pi^{\mathsf T}M = \pi^{\mathsf T}$. Therefore if we multiply the definition of $F$ on the left by $\pi^{\mathsf T}$, we get  $$\pi^{\mathsf T}F =  \pi^{\mathsf T}J + \pi^{\mathsf T}MH - \pi^{\mathsf T}H = \pi^{\mathsf T}J +  \pi^{\mathsf T}H - \pi^{\mathsf T}H =  \pi^{\mathsf T}J.$$ Now, comparing the two sides: on the left, $\pi^{\mathsf T}F$ is a row vector whose $i^{\text{th}}$ entry is $\pi_i F_{ii}$. On the right, $\pi^{\mathsf T}J$ is a row vector whose $i^{\text{th}}$ entry is $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \dots + \pi_n = 1$. Therefore $\pi_i F_{ii} = 1$, which tells us what the diagonal entries of $F$ are: they are the reciprocals of the stationary probabilities $\pi$.

Comment: Would you have any reference that explained this proof thoroughly like you did?

Comment: Sorry, no reference. In principle, all this is there in the paper; it just takes some experience reading papers like this.

Comment: Could you help me with the later parts? I'm not sure if I should make a new post for this, but:

(1) How does the matrix $X = (I - M + M^*)^{-1}(J - 2mD)$ satisfies $(I - M)H = J - 2mD$ in the place of H? I have no idea where the author pulled that from.
(2) In the final formula, where do $v_{kt}$, $v_{ks}$ and $\lambda_k$ come from? I believe those are eigenvectors and eigenvalues of some matrix. Are those from the matrix X?